# Why is my Python loop functioning returning NaN's?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nan

I have this loop below that pulls multiple stock information from an API and stores the data in dictionary format along with the other tickers in `stocks`.

```
d = {}
m = {}
for x in stocks:
    d[x] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(x, start= window, end=today)
    d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
    d[x]['Date'] = d[x].index
    m[x] = data.get_quote_yahoo(x)['marketCap']
    
sp500 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(spy, start= window, end=today)
sp500 = sp500['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

The code runs fine except for one line: `d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()`

The code line above finds the return rate using month as the frequency. Because I'm trying to find this variable for all stocks, I added it in the loop above. When I run the code, I get a bunch of NaN's for row values of `d[x]['Growth']`, the rest of the code works fine.

[image: this is an example of where my loops goes wrong, check out the NaN under the Growth column, this is the same for all the stocks in the loop.]

I get `d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()` to work when it's not in the loop.

Check the image below:
[image: The code works fine here]

What is wrong with how I structured the loop? Can't seem to figure this one out, looking for some help.

EDIT:
Following up to @RichieV comment, if anyone wants to run the code to replicate my notebook, copy and paste this.

```
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

stocks = ['INTU','FTNT','MANH']
spy = 'SPY'
years = -3

def rolling_window52w(d, years):
    try:
        return d.replace(year = d.year + years)
    except ValueError:
        return d + (date(d.year + years, 1, 1) - date(d.year, 1, 1))

window_obj = rolling_window52w(date.today(), years)
today_obj = date.today()    
    
window = str(rolling_window52w(date.today(), years))
today = str(date.today())
#d = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

yf.pdr_override()

d = {}
m = {}
for x in stocks:
    d[x] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(x, start= window, end=today)
    d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
    d[x]['Date'] = d[x].index
    m[x] = data.get_quote_yahoo(x)['marketCap']
    
sp500 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(spy, start= window, end=today)
sp500 = sp500['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

Comment: When you run it outside of the loop, notice that the index still only has dates at the end of each month.  If you assign that back to the original df it will match rows based on that index.  All other rows will have nans

Comment: Please always include all the relevant code for others to reproduce your outcome... you are missing the import of `get_data_yahoo` and the assignment of `stocks`, `window`, and today... don't make others work extra if it can be avoided

Comment: @RichieV I have added my notebook in the original post. Thank you for reminding me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by calling `.resample('M')` pandas is creating a new series with the end of the month as index.

Even though you try to fix that by calling `.ffill()`, the resampled series has no `NaNs` to fill (as exposed by your second image-table). Your out-of-loop example has no effect when calling the forward fill, as it only contains rows for end of month.

Perhaps you were attempting to get the `.pct_change` for each month and fill the full month with that value. In that case you might consider changing to `.bfill` instead of `.ffill` and calling the fill only after the series has been aligned with the full df, to include all rows.

Replace:

```
d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

With:

```
d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Adj Close'].resample('M').pct_change()
d[x]['Growth'] = d[x]['Growth'].bfill()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I understand what is going on with my loop now. After testing your suggestion, I got an error: `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'pct_change'
`     Trying to search for an alternative now, no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your index (`Date`) has sampled per day i.e you have a reading per day. When you do

```
df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill()
```

you are resamapling at interval of month and `ffill` will forward fill the missing `Adj Close` values for the sampled intervals (per month). So you get a series whose index is sampled per Month (freq='M'). When you assign these values using

```
df['Growth'] = df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill()
```

[LHS = RHS]

Since the index of `df` is sample at frequency of 'D' but your right hand side is sampled at 'M' the missing values of left hand side will be written as NaNs

Example:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/21/2000', periods=15, freq='D')
df  = pd.DataFrame({ 'Adj Close':  np.random.randn(len(index))}, index=index)
df['Growth'] = df['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill()
print (df)
```

Output:

```
            Adj Close   Growth
2000-01-21  -1.709513      NaN
2000-01-22  -0.133944      NaN
2000-01-23  -0.110338      NaN
2000-01-24  -1.753118      NaN
2000-01-25  -1.023976      NaN
2000-01-26   0.078570      NaN
2000-01-27  -0.219072      NaN
2000-01-28   1.394198      NaN
2000-01-29  -0.693795      NaN
2000-01-30  -0.690569      NaN
2000-01-31   0.740330  0.74033
2000-02-01   0.033305      NaN
2000-02-02  -0.770007      NaN
2000-02-03  -0.862028      NaN
2000-02-04   2.346838      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Found a better solution for appending multi-timeframe indicator columns to my minute OHCLV stock data as shown below. A beautiful one-linerL

```
bars['min20ma20'] = bars.closes.resample('20min').last().rolling(window=20).mean().reindex(bars.index, method='ffill')
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW**

I was running into a very similar issue and realized that I first needed to resample (from 1min bars to 20min bars) the whole dataframe, and then calculate the rolling mean for a single column.

```
bars = bars.resample("20min").last()    
bars['min20ma20s'] = bars.closes.rolling(window=20).mean()
```

If you have other columns in your dataframe that you care about, you'll want to aggregate those during the resample as well. i.e. a "volume" column for typical stock data. For that you can use the code below:

```
bars = bars.resample("20min").agg({
    'opens': 'first',
    'highs': 'max',
    'lows': 'min',
    'closes': 'last',
    'volumes': 'sum',
    'todays_volumes': 'last',
    'vwaps': 'last'
})
```

My final full working code:

```
data = {
    "ev": "AM",             # Event Type ( A = Second Agg, AM = Minute Agg )
    "sym": "MSFT",          # Symbol Ticker
    "v": 10204,             # Tick Volume
    "av": 200304,           # Accumulated Volume ( Today )
    "op": 114.04,           # Today's official opening price
    "vw": 114.4040,         # VWAP (Volume Weighted Average Price)
    "o": 114.11,            # Tick Open Price
    "c": 114.14,            # Tick Close Price
    "h": 114.19,            # Tick High Price
    "l": 114.09,            # Tick Low Price
    "a": 114.1314,          # Tick Average / VWAP Price
    "s": 1536036818784,     # Tick Start Timestamp ( Unix MS )
    "e": 1536036818784,     # Tick End Timestamp ( Unix MS )
}

bars = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [{
        'times': data['e'],
        'symbols': data['sym'],
        'opens': data['o'],
        'highs': data['h'],
        'lows': data['l'],
        'closes': data['c'],
        'volumes': data['v'],
        'todays_volumes': data['av'],
        'vwaps': data['vw']
    }]
)
bars['times'] = pd.to_datetime(
    bars['times'],
    unit='ms'
).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
bars.index = bars['times']

# Compile and prepare incoming data
indicator = None
for _ in range(500):
    data['e'] += (1 * 60 * 1000)
    bar_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        [{
            'times': data['e'],
            'symbols': data['sym'],
            'opens': data['o'],
            'highs': data['h'],
            'lows': data['l'],
            'closes': data['c'],
            'volumes': data['v'],
            'todays_volumes': data['av'],
            'vwaps': data['vw']
        }]
    )
    bar_df['times'] = pd.to_datetime(
        bar_df['times'],
        unit='ms'
    ).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
    bar_df.index = bar_df['times']
    bars = bars.append(bar_df)

    # Calculate 20min 20 period moving average after each min bar received
    bars = bars.resample("20min").agg({
        'opens': 'first',
        'highs': 'max',
        'lows': 'min',
        'closes': 'last',
        'volumes': 'sum',
        'todays_volumes': 'last',
        'vwaps': 'last'
    })
    bars['min20ma20s'] = bars.closes.rolling(window=20).mean()
```

Final Bars Output

[image]